# Package icons are not displayed on the phone

Tags: devextreme

After creating the template, the application icons do not appear. I do not see the icons when I set up the phone after I made the apk .
why so. When the template is deleted, the icon appears on the phone. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the issue is that PhoneGap has changed the icons path. We are about to deliver the corresponding fix in the following thread: [The package icons path is invalid when PhoneGap cli-6.5.0 is used](https://www.devexpress.com/issue=T479503)